# Categories and Sub Categories Query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Im trying to set up a database so that I can query it and get all products out for a category and query it for a particular sub category.

I have a products table

```
id | title | category_id (fk)
```

And a categories table:

```
id | title | parent
```

So if the categories looked like this:

```
id | title | parent
1  | books | null
2  | crime | 1
3  | spy   | 2
4  | dvd   | null
5  | cd    | null
```

And products:

```
id | title | category_id (fk)
1  | 007   | 3
1  | Murder| 2
```

A product would belong to one category. Above the '007' product belongs to the 'Spy' sub category. 'Murder' belongs to the 'Crime' sub category. Both belong to the parent 'books' category.

How would I query the database to:

1. Get all products for a sub category (in example for spy I would get '007')
2. Get all products for a parent category, so if I want all products for books I would get both '007' and 'Murder'.

Comment: See partial solution in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663839/getting-sub-category-info-in-parent-category-in-laravel/50664143#50664143](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663839/getting-sub-category-info-in-parent-category-in-laravel/50664143#50664143) or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901803/get-all-pages-from-category-and-all-sub-categories/50664476#50664476](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901803/get-all-pages-from-category-and-all-sub-categories/50664476#50664476)

Answer (score 1):

You can just find all subcategories of a parent category and then use that to fetch the associated products. The solution below assumes you have [Eloquent Models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) for each table you described, so a `Category`and a `Product` model.

The `Product` model doesn't require any additional code, it just needs to exist. The `Category` model will have to look as follows:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        // Build an array containing the parent category ID and all subcategory IDs found
        $categoryIds = array_merge([$this->id], $this->subcategoryIds());

        // Find all products that match the retrieved category IDs 
        return Product::whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)->get();
    }

    protected function subcategoryIds($id = null, &$ids= [])
    {
        // If no ID is passed, set the current model ID as the parent
        if (is_null($id)) {
            $id = $this->id;
        }

        // Find subcategory IDs
        $categoryIds = $this->query()->where('parent', $id)->lists('id');

        // Add each ID to the list and recursively find other subcategory IDs
        foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
            $ids[] = $categoryId;
            $ids += $this->subcategoryIds($categoryId, $ids);
        }

        return $ids;
    }
}
```

Now to find the products within the `Books` category, you just need to find it by `id` and call the `products` method on the model:

```php
$products = App\Category::find(1)->products();
```