# Getting sub category info in parent category in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have multi level category where structure is like:

```
Parent
 - first child
  -- second child
 - another child
```

**What I want to do is,** getting products in all child levels in `Parent Page` so that I can have all products of `parent, first child, second child,  another child` inside `Parent`.

**What I have so far,** currently I can get products of `Parent, first child & another child` but I'm not able to get products of my `second child`.

## Codes

```
public function totalcategoriessubs($catslug) {
    $category = Category::where('slug','=',$catslug)->with('childs')->first();
    //testing this
    // $products = Product::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($catslug,$category)
    // {
    //   $q->where(function($q) use ($catslug,$category) {
    //     $q->where('slug',$catslug)->orWhere('category_id',$category->id);
    //   });
    // })->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

    $products = Product::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($catslug, $category) {
      $q->where(function($q) use ($catslug,$category) {
        $q->where('slug',$catslug) //works
          ->WhereHas('childs') //works
          ->WhereHas('childs.childs') //not working
          ->orWhere('category_id',$category->id); //works
        });
      })->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
    //end testing
    return view('front.categoriessubs', compact('products', 'category'));
  }
```

## models

`Product model`

```
public function category(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

`Category model`

```
public function categories()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
  }

  public function childs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'category_id','id') ;
  }

  public function parent()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id');
  }

  public function isParent()
  {
      return !$this->category_id ? true : false; // if category_id is null => is a Parent Category
  }

  public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
  }
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the nested childs with simple trick.

only use     `protected $appends = ['childs', 'products'];` in Model.

In Category.php Model

```
protected appends = ['childs'];


public function categories()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
  }

  public function childs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'category_id','id') ;
  }

  public function parent()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id');
  }

  public function isParent()
  {
      return !$this->category_id ? true : false; // if category_id is null => is a Parent Category
  }

  public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
  }
```

Now You can get the Childs using

```
Category::with('childs')->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'appends' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)`

Comment: i changed it to `$appends` and now it works but my results are the same as before (still can't get `second child` products)

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    /**
     * @var Category
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    protected $query;

    /**
     * Controller constructor.
     * @param Category $category
     */
    public function __construct(Category $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->query = $this->category->newQuery();
    }

    public function home()
    {
        print_r($this->getAncestorCategoriesE1(2, 3)->toArray());
        print_r($this->getSubCategoriesE2(null, 7)->toArray());
        print_r($this->getSubCategoriesE2(1, 7)->toArray());
        print_r($this->getSubCategoriesE1(null, 8)->toArray());
        print_r($this->getSubCategoriesE1(1, 8)->toArray());
    }

    /**
     * Easy method but select all
     *
     * @param $categoryId
     * @param int $depth
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|string|static[]
     */
     public function getAncestorCategoriesE1($categoryId, $depth = 1) 
     {
         if (!is_numeric($depth) || $depth < 1) {
             return 'INvalid depth parameter';
         }

        $parents = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < $depth; $i++) {
            $parents[] = 'parent';
        }

        $rel = implode('.', $parents);

        return $this->category->with($rel)->find($categoryId);
    }

    /**
     * Easy method but select all
     *
     * @param null $categoryId
     * @param int $depth
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|string|static[]
     */
    public function getSubCategoriesE1($categoryId = null, $depth = 1) {
        if (!is_numeric($depth) || $depth < 1) {
            return 'INvalid depth parameter';
        }

        $children = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $depth; $i++) {
            $children[] = 'children';
        }

        $rel = implode('.', $children);
        $this->addCategoryCondition($categoryId);

        return $this->category->with($rel)->get();
    }

    /**
     * @param null $categoryId
     * @param int $depth
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public function getSubCategoriesE2($categoryId = null, $depth = 4)
    {
        $this->addCategoryCondition($categoryId);
        $this->pushSelectInQuery($this->query);
        $this->pushWithInQuery($this->query, $depth);
        return $this->query->get();
    }

    /**
     * @param $query
     */
    public function pushSelectInQuery($query)
    {
        $query->select('name', 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    /**
     * @param $query
     * @param int $depth
     */
    public function pushWithInQuery($query, $depth = 1)
    {
        $query->with(['children' => function($query) use ($depth) {
            $this->pushSelectInQuery($query);
            if (1 != $depth) {
                $this->pushWithInQuery($query, --$depth);
            }
        }]);
    }

    /**
     * @param $categoryId
     */
    public function addCategoryCondition($categoryId)
    {
        if (is_null($categoryId)) {
            $this->query->whereNull('parent_id');
        } else {
            $this->query->where('parent_id', $categoryId);
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'parent_id', 'name'
    ];

    /**
     *
     */
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class,  'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

In controller has DRY I fix it later!!!