# laravel child paren print recursively

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('place', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('place', 'parent_id');
}
```

my model has this two methods, so I want to print all the childs or parents recursively, as far as I know each time I call:

```
$item->children() or $item->parent()
```

a separete mysql query is executed, so is there way to get all of them in one query and print them recursively? is there a built-in method or should  I write my own function for this? if I should write my own function at least tell me please how to get them all in one query using this eloquent laravel Model methods

Comment: see answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663839/getting-sub-category-info-in-parent-category-in-laravel/50664143#50664143](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663839/getting-sub-category-info-in-parent-category-in-laravel/50664143#50664143)

Comment: even [EagerLoading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) will have difficulties dealing with this..

Comment: If that post help you let me know about it

Comment: @Davit too complicated that controller functions are

Comment: there is a 2 solution of tasks